# React router -- How to send props without query params or Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to send data to another route, but don't want to send it in query params.

I don't want a new store for every route, nor do I want a store that simply holds all routes / params separately from where they are sent / consumed.

Is there a standard way to specify props for an upcoming route?

Comment: Are you already using Redux or the Flux pattern?

Comment: Using Redux, but I don't view this as app state, more like a temporary variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on the react-router [location api docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location).

```js
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/view-user',
  state: { userId }
});
```

This seems great for interstitial, standalone modal pages.

May need to specify a fallback if the state is missing, but haven't quite gotten that far.

```js
if (!this.props.location.state) this.props.router.goBack();
```

or

```
const locations = this.props.location.pathname.split('/');
// do something 
this.props.route.push(locations.join('/'));
```

Comment: Was about to suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sending the information in the query param, then you can put it in some other kind of store that can also be associated with the route.

You can wrap the router.push() call with your own function that takes an extra object you want to pass along. Something like...

```js
function navigateTo(url, extraData) {
  if (extraData !== undefined) { 
    saveExtraDataForRoute(url, extraData);
  }
  router.push(url);
}
```

In react-router, there is an onEnter prop associated with the route that specifies a function to call. The code in this function can retrieve the extra data and do whatever you want to do with it.

```js
function onMyScreenEnter() {
  const extraData = getExtraDataForRoute(url);
  goCrazyNutsWithYourExtraData(extraData);
}
```

You'd supply the two functions saveExtraDataForRoute() and getExtraDataForRoute(). They could use your store (e.g. Redux), set values of a singleton object, or use LocalStorage. But essentially, to save the data so it's retrievable by URL later, you'd be saying something like:

```js
extraDataStore[url] = extraData;
```

The other thing you may wish to look into is using a POST method with react-router. I haven't done this, and am not sure how well it works. Here is a link: [How to Handle Post Request in Isomorphic React + React Router Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079158/how-to-handle-post-request-in-isomorphic-react-react-router-application)